# Android: create directory in instrumentation test case

Tags: android, unit-testing

I want to create a tmp directory in my instrumentation test case. I have tried 
`this.getInstrumentation().getContext().getDir("tmp", 0)`, but it failed to create the dir under data/data/package-name directory. I guess, there's some difference between instrumentation test package and normal package.

Could someone help me on this?

Comment: test package's internal storage

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your application project has package name `com.example`, and your test project has package name `com.example.test`.

```
// This will create app_tmp1 directory under data/data/com.example.test/
this.getInstrumentation().getContext().getDir("tmp1", 0);

// This will create app_tmp2 directory under data/data/com.example/
this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext().getDir("tmp2", 0);
```

Hope this helps.